# Fetching from CORS-API not allowed for localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch

I'm working on a React App which needs to fetch data from an Api.
I made it work with fake data.

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          return response.json();
      })
      .then((json) => {
          return json;
      })
```

Now i wanted to get data from our local Api with Apigility.

```
fetch('http://localserver:8081/news')
      .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          return response.json();
      })
      .then((json) => {
          return json;
      })
```

But i get `net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (The origin "http://localho.st:5000" is not authorized)`. The app was created with create-react-app and gets served by its run script.

Now the thing is it works, when i enter `http://localserver:8081/news` in Firefox and Edge. I receive the json data. The same when trying it with my phone, curl or an api tester.

This is the answer when trying to fetch from the app:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 The origin "http://localhost:3000" is not authorized
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.30
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Thu, 07 Oct 2021 12:59:08 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

And when calling from browser:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/hal+json
Vary: Origin
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.30
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="Service"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Thu, 07 Oct 2021 13:03:08 GMT
Content-Length: 133933
```

I've read about setting up a proxy to get CORS calls, but i wondered if there are other solutions to this problem.

EDIT:
localserver:

```
GET /news HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.254.2.10:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 403 The origin "http://localhost:3000" is not authorized
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.30
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Thu, 07 Oct 2021 14:15:22 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

```
Host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

HTTP/3 200 OK
date: Thu, 07 Oct 2021 14:17:37 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
x-powered-by: Express
x-ratelimit-limit: 1000
x-ratelimit-remaining: 999
x-ratelimit-reset: 1633547463
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000
vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
access-control-allow-credentials: true
cache-control: max-age=43200
pragma: no-cache
expires: -1
x-content-type-options: nosniff
etag: W/"6b80-Ybsq/K6GwwqrYkAsFxqDXGC7DoM"
via: 1.1 vegur
cf-cache-status: HIT
age: 4307
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=qYfd07Dc%2BG9NUgzVp1DHMPuBcDx8UOvlbWfDD51OGSN8s74yaJFooN99m7nG4NSHV%2BeqY78Qw%2Bb7ozFdWCmF8ngPRnQPc3tlVdrSwGy8TKWYLwWSEYI4YE88GU5yyErQ8P5jLa5tUkPnB4FA6mg7"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 69a7c10bdbf66d8f-MUC
content-encoding: br
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400, h3-28=":443"; ma=86400, h3-27=":443"; ma=86400
```

Comment: Browsers send along cookies, fetch by default doesn't. Try adding `credentials: "include"` to your [fetch options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#parameters).

Comment: `Access to fetch at 'http://localserver:8081/news' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.` Unfortunately i cant change the Origin and i think its required here.

Comment: @Pachari Requests with credentials (e.g. sent by `fetch` with `credentials: "include"`) won't work if the server responds with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. Please also tell us what you mean by "calling from browser". Do you mean visiting the URL in question as a top-level navigation?

Comment: You should edit your question and show us the responses to the preflight requests to `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` and to `http://localserver:8081/news`.

Comment: @jub0bs, do you mean the requests? I dont know how to get them in Firefox/Edge.

Comment: Why can't you (temporarily) set your react server as the origin? It's your own server.

Comment: I don't have the permissions to do so. The server is in my network but it's not mine.

Comment: Open the developer tools in Firefox, navigate to the Network tab; you'll see the requests and responses there.

Comment: In that case the only solution is to use your own proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Create-React-App comes with a simple way to handle this: add a proxy field to your package.json file as shown below. In this case, a request is made from server A to server B

```
"proxy": "http://localserver:8081/",
```

Comment: This seems to be an oauth2 problem, not a cors problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can run a local reverse proxy to get the API calls from the same origin (say mapping localhost:3000/api/news to localhost:8081/news) but then it'd probably be easier to set up a CORS proxy.

You could try to make the API JSONP and circumvent the same origin policy that way, but this is likely also more hairy than setting up a CORS proxy.

Long story short: Whenever you make requests across origins, CORS needs to be set up.

Comment: That's the thing though: OP has CORS set up as you can see from the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the header. This seems to be an auth problem, not a CORS problem